# I want to build an iphone app that would require accessing the log files of the user

Tags: iphone, logging, logfiles

This access will be for the users benefit.

Is this allowed? If not why not?

Or is it restricted ie: They allow it, but don't let the developer record the information.

I have seen numerous log apps on itunes store so how is it different from viewing this?

Comment: Log files in terms of what ? which log files ? please clarify, this is vague information.

Comment: I'm referring specifically to being able to access the time spent on specific apps. ie the log files which tell me how long i've been on a certain app

Answer (score 1):

No it not possible, apps can't read files that are not within the applications sandbox folders.

Comment: How do you find out what files are within the applications sandbox

Comment: Only the files that you placed there.

Comment: I'm referring specifically to being able to access the time spent on specific apps. ie the log files which tell me how long i've been on a certain app

Comment: You can not access these files.